# AWS Redshift - get_cluster_credentials in Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

Im trying to automate a process for Redshift in Lambda. To securely store the password we can use,

1. KMS with Env variables
2. secret manager
3. use get_cluster_credentials API

I want to use  `get_cluster_credentials` for this.

There is a great blog post here: https://blog.mitocgroup.com/aws-lambda-to-redshift-connection-using-iam-authentication-and-nat-gateway-b40c6002082b

He had done this and complied his own `psycopg2`. Im trying to implement the same. Im getting the error in Lambda like Password authentication failed for the user `IAM:my_iamuser`. I tried to print the password and used it directly in psql shell and its working fine. But in lambda its not working.

### Error:

```py
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "IAM:my_iamuser"
: OperationalError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/pgcode.py", line 45, in lambda_handler
    host=REDSHIFT_ENDPOINT)
  File "/var/task/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "IAM:my_iamuser"
```

Comment: I have the same exact issue

Comment: Previously they were using medium.com I have commented this issue, but now I think they have hosted on their own. May be create an issue on his Github  page(https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2/issues)

Comment: turns out i was passing the wrong values to my psycopg2.connect. Dumb mistake on my part